# Can the Wizzair Discount Club membership holder's companion travel without the holder himself?

Tags: air-travel, wizz-air

We booked 2 tickets using discount club to complete the booking. During booking it was said that you have to be a passenger in order to use Wizzair Discount Club. But now something came up and the membership holder cannot travel.

My question is whether the other traveler can still use the flight?

If not, what are our options? Can we amend the booking in any way? Is the money we payed refundable in any way (or can be reused)?

Comment: Can i change the traveler that is the holder of the membership and pay only the fare difference?

Comment: If by changing the traveler you mean removing him from booking then yes it's possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all the relevant information at [Wizz Discount Club Terms and Conditions](https://book.wizzair.com/en-GB/travel_services/WECTermsandC).

As you can see from there:

> 1.10... The club member must remain a passenger in the booking at all time for the other passengers to beneficiate from the club fares. If
>   the club member is removed from the booking, the regular fare will be
>   applicable to all remaining passengers and the fare difference will
>   need to be paid. Alternatively, one of the other passengers can become a
>   club member to keep club benefits for the remaining passengers.

So, **don't worry, your friend can still use the flight if you are still on the booking (not necessarily traveling)**.

However, if you will remove yourself from the booking (which is unlikely), then your friend has to pay the fare difference, which is most of the times 10 € for the flight + 5 € for the baggage. However, if the difference is larger than 30 €, your friend can become a club member himself for 29.99 €, as was suggested above.